# I have to choose my microphone every time I need to use it

Tags: 14.04, settings, microphone

I'm on ubuntu 14.04 with a mac. My problem is that whenever I start up my computer, my microphone doesnt work. System settings defaults to "digital input S-PDIF," but for some reason that doesnt work. I have to go in manually to the settings app and change my microphone under "input" to "Microphone."

Even after that, sometimes I have to mute the microphone and unmute it to get it to register sound.

I was wondering if you guys knew how I could set the default microphone to "microphone" rather than SPIF, and maybe how to solve the mute-unmute problem

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, This issue went away when I upgraded to 14.10.